# How does a gaussian beam change as it passes through a non linear crystal (for example undergoing SPDC or SHG)

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, crystals

What happens to the beam waist and divergence angle as it is used to pump a second harmonic generation or parametric down-conversion process? Intuitively, it seems that the waist should remain same. But is this true? Will the divergence angle of the beam change since the output photons are of a different wavelength? 
All in all, what is the general method to deal with Gaussian stream of photons undergoing some scattering process? Will the ABCD formalism work is some modified way?